# FFT in Matlab in order to find signal frequency and create a graph with peaks

Tags: matlab, fft

I have data from an accelerometer and made a graph of acceleration(y-axis) and time (x-axis). The frequency rate of the sensor is arround 100 samples per second. but there is no equally spaced time (for example it goes from 10.046,10.047,10.163 etc) the pace is not const. And there is no function of the signal i get. I need to find the frequency of the signal and made a graph of frequency(Hz x-axis) and acceleration (y-axis). but i don't know which code of FFT suits my case. (sorry for bad english)
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about signal processing (see [dsp.se]), not programming

Answer (score 0):

For an FFT to work you will need to reconstruct the signal you have with with a regular interval. There are two ways you can do this:

Interpolate the data you already have to make an accurate guess at where the signal would be at a regular interval. However, this FFT may contain significant inaccuracies.

OR

Adjust the device reading from the accelerometer incorporate an accurate timer such that results are always transmitted at regular intervals. This is what I would recommend.